# Finding most sold product

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the most sold product by Margaret Peacock which brought the
most profit in the month of November, the database is the one in w3schools.com in case you guys want to see the structure. Here is the query I wrote

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName, p.ProductName, od.Quantity, p.Price, o.OrderDate
FROM
  Employees e
  INNER JOIN Orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE 
  o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-11-01' AND '1996-11-30'
  AND e.FirstName = 'Margaret'
  AND e.LastName = 'Peacock'
GROUP BY
  e.FirstName,
  e.LastName,
  p.ProductName,
  od.Quantity,
  p.Price,
  o.OrderDate
ORDER BY p.Price DESC
```

Here is the result:

```
FirstName   LastName    ProductName   Quantity   Price    OrderDate
Margaret    Peacock     Côte de Blaye      10             263.5   1996-11-22
Margaret    Peacock    Thüringer Rostbratwurs  35            123.79   1996-11-22
Margaret    Peacock    Rössle Sauerkraut       30              45.6   1996-11-22
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you mean the product whose `Quantity`*`Price` is bigger?

Comment: The Cote de Blaye is too expensive (unless you are using old Francs, or Belgian Francs)

Comment: The answer depends on the rdbms, which you did not specify.

Comment: Thanks guys, neutrino that's exactly what I was looking for :) thanks, sorry guys, forgot to mention I'm a beginner as a DBA, just finished with the course and recently got certified so I'm still trying to get my head around a few things.

Answer (score 0):

A max function usually works, but you would need some means of knowing the cost to derive actual profit.

```
SELECT MAX(p.PRICE - p.[Cost Field])
FROM
  Employees e
  INNER JOIN Orders o ON e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE 
  o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-11-01' AND '1996-11-30'
  AND e.FirstName = 'Margaret'
  AND e.LastName = 'Peacock'
GROUP BY
  e.FirstName,
  e.LastName,
  p.ProductName,
  od.Quantity,
  p.Price,
  o.OrderDate
ORDER BY p.Price DESC
```